# Default schema for new users

Tags: google-admin-sdk

we are trying to use google apps' SAML capabilities for our custom apps. In order to pass user roles to our apps we are looking into custom user fields (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas). One thing we are struggling with is to automatically assign a default schema to newly created google apps accounts.

Is this somehow doable? Do we miss some option?

Or is there a different approach for this topic?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code and error logs (if there is any)?

Comment: Hi, we've covered this topic in the meantime with a small cli tool our office admins are using. So it's solved for us. But haven't checked any further.